# Is there a way to make multiple functions run concurrently in a Go backend?

Tags: go, concurrency

Suppose that you want to introduce an entry into a database, let's say, for lack of a better example, you want to introduce a book entry into a books and authors database. So, my mental model for this insertion would be something like this.

1. I first insert the book related fields of a struct into the database using this piece of code:

```
query := `
        INSERT INTO books(book_id,title,publisher,year,page_count,genres)
        VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)
        RETURNING id,book_id,title,publisher,year,page_count,genres
    `

    args := []interface{}{
        entry.Book.Hash,
        entry.Book.Title,
        entry.Book.Publisher,
        entry.Book.Year,
        entry.Book.PageCount,
        pq.Array(entry.Book.Genres)}

    err := tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args...).Scan(
        &read.Book.ID,
        &read.Book.Hash,
        &read.Book.Title,
        &read.Book.Publisher,
        &read.Book.Year,
        &read.Book.PageCount,
        pq.Array(&read.Book.Genres))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

2. Then I insert the author names into a separate author table, checking that if the author already exists, then the code should just increase the books_authored counter by one. The code for that operation is the following:

```
query = `
        WITH filter1 AS(
            SELECT
            UNNEST($1::TEXT[]) AS name,
            UNNEST($2::TEXT[]) AS author_id,
            1 as books_authored
        ), finished AS(
            INSERT INTO authors(name,author_id,books_authored)
            SELECT name, author_id, books_authored FROM filter1
            ON CONFLICT (author_id) DO UPDATE
            SET books_authored = authors.books_authored + 1
            RETURNING id, name, author_id, books_authored
        )
        SELECT array_agg(id), array_agg(name), array_agg(author_id), array_agg(books_authored) FROM finished
    `

    args = []interface{}{pq.Array(entry.Authors.List), pq.Array(entry.Authors.Hash)}
    err = tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args...).Scan(
        pq.Array(&read.List.ID),
        pq.Array(&read.List.Name),
        pq.Array(&read.List.Identifier),
        pq.Array(&read.List.Books_authored),
    )

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

3. Then, I make an entry into a book/authors table that just relates the book id with the different author ids. Using the following code.

```
    query = `
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT book_id, author_id FROM
        UNNEST($1::TEXT[]) AS book_id,
        UNNEST($2::TEXT[]) AS author_id 
  ), finished AS (
    INSERT INTO book_author_link(book_id, author_id)
    SELECT book_id, author_id FROM cte
    ON CONFLICT (book_id, author_id) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING book_id, author_id
  )
  SELECT array_agg(book_id), array_agg(author_id) FROM finished
  
    `

    args = []interface{}{pq.Array([]string{entry.Book.Hash}), pq.Array(entry.Authors.Hash)}

    return tx.QueryRowContext(ctx, query, args...).Scan(
        pq.Array(entry.Authors.List),
        pq.Array(entry.Authors.Hash),
    )
```

Everything is done using a  SQL transaction in order to create an entry only if all of the previous steps are done. So my question was if I could do the first and second steps concurrently, check if both goroutines were completed succesfully and proceed with the third step.

For more information, I did try to use the `sync/mutex` package but to no avail, I don't know if locking all the goroutines using the http package locks all of the other processes that are running in the background. But when I used the `sync/waitGroup`.

Comment: Yes, sure you can. The simplest for your use case is probably using `errgroup`: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup#example-Group-Parallel. It does a lot of the manual sync work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry for a glib response, but Go is about doing things concurrently, and it does not matter whether those things are executing SQL statements in an RDBMS or performing HTTP requests or doing math or whatever. So, if you have no idea how to coordinate two goroutines (from a third one) you have a basic gap in your knowledge of the language, and so your question is not really fit for SO. Please consider fully completing [the Tour](https://go.dev/tour/) first and then read up on [Go concurrency patterns](https://www.google.com/search?q=concurrency+site%3Ago.dev%2Fblog).

Comment: You cannot use a single PostgreSQL transaction concurrently. That's not a limitation of Go but one of PostgreSQL. It simply doesn't support concurrent queries over a single connection.

Comment: You can't make code concurrent using `sync/mutex` or `sync/waitgroup`. Both of those are tools for synchronization, i.e. controlling or reducing concurrency. Can you show the code you used to actually attempt to run these concurrently?

Comment: This is not a realistic example by the way, there should never be a "books_authored" column in a database like this. Instead your books should have an author, and then they can be counted with a very simple count query. If you want to learn a new concept, you should try to find realistic use cases to do so. When it comes to databases and concurrency I'm afraid it is really boring and tedious; batch importing of large volumes of data comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly **can**; see other answers for how to do that.

But before rushing to implement something you **can** do, you should always first stop and consider whether you *should*.

In this case, let's consider what would happen if you tried to concurrently add a `book` and `author` for a book that is already present (assuming that the `book_id` is something sensible like an ISBN code, not just some artificial id):

The `book` INSERT will fail, but the `author` INSERT may still conflict and (wrongly) UPDATE the author with an additional `books_authored`.

You will now get a different, *incorrect* result when selecting `books_authored` for that author vs the actual number of books currently recorded as authored by them.

That assumes that the `author` already exists, which again relies heavily on how author identity is determined.

If there exists the possibility of duplicating authors by having entries inserted for the same person multiple times e.g. with different spelling (or misspelling) of their name, then you could end up in an even worse mess, particularly if a book has multiple authors where some are identified correctly and some are incorrect dupes of existing authors.

Some `author` records may have `books_authored` values that match the results recorded in `book_author_link` while others will not.

### To Reiterate

So yes, you can do what you want to do concurrently, but it isn't as simple as figuring out **how** to execute your current logic concurrently.  You need to *change* your logic and you may also need to change your data model.  You may conclude that the changes that are necessary are not actually desirable.

You shouldn't just **want** concurrency, you should **need** it, and in this case you demonstrably don't need it because introducing it **creates** problems.

Leading to the question: *what problem was concurrency intended to **solve***?

There may be other solutions to that.

Comment: Well, this was a good response, I think. Well I am still learning Golang and I just wanted to implement something to see if it works. But I'll keep it in mind if I really need concurrency in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Since your 3rd query depends on first two.
We can run first two queries in go routines, and wait for those two routines to finish, since it depends on the successful execution of those queries instead of WaitGroup, @TehSphinX suggested to use errGroup

```
g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(context.Background())
g.Go(func() error {
    // INSERT INTO books....
    // ....
    //
    // return err got from query execution nil or nor nil
    return err
})
g.Go(func() error {
    // INSERT INTO authors....
    // ....
    //
    // return err got from query execution nil or nor nil
    return err
})

// check if any one of query failed or not here
err := g.Wait()
if err != nil {
    // ROLL BACK HERE
}
// INSERT INTO book_author_link here
// 
// 
// if last one fails roll back
if err != nil {
    // ROLL BACK HERE
}
// COMMIT HERE
```

Above method will run two queries concurrently and last one will wait still first two finish up.

you can still achieve this using waitGroups and channels but this looks easier and cleaner to me.

**THOUGH I DO NOT KNOW WEATHER DB WILL SUPPORT CONCURRENCY IN TRANSACTION OR NOT**

Comment: The second query also depends on the outcome of the first.  See my answer.

Answer (score -4):

I'm pretty new to GoLang too, but you could use channels for this. A minimalistic example:
Create two channels of type bool and give one to each function. Each goroutine puts the result of success (true/false) onto its channel. Your third goroutine could run permanent in the background and listen to both channels. If both entries are true, let your magic happen :). The third goroutine could look like this:

```
func Success(ch1, ch2 chan bool) {
    for val1ok := range ch1 {
        for val2ok := range ch2 {
            if val1ok && val2ok {
                fmt.Println("All Okay")
                break
            }
            fmt.Println("Not Okay")
        }
    }
}
```

For you, of course, there will be more logic. For example: structs and so on and does the book match the author? Might be an idea to give both goroutines something like a primary key for each pair, cache everything inside the third goroutine and assign it back together. Don't forget to remove if a match has been processed or a specific time is exceeded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).